# Tensorflow: chaining tf.gather() produces IndexedSlices warning

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm running into an issue where chaining `tf.gather()` indexing produces the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py:90: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.           
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
```

The scenario arises when one layer indexes into the input layer, performs some operation on the corresponding slice, and then the next layer indexes into the result. Here's a representative example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

## 10-Dimensional data will be fed to the model
X = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, [10, None] )

## W works with the first 3 features of a sample
W = tf.Variable( tf.ones( [5, 3] ) )
Xi = tf.gather( X, [0,1,2] )
mm = tf.matmul( W, Xi )

## Indexing into the result produces a warning during backprop
h = tf.gather( mm, [0,1] )
...
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize( loss )
```

The warning arises upon definition of `train_step` and goes away if the second `tf.gather()` call is taken away. The warning also goes away if `X` is provided with an explicit number of samples (e.g., `[10, 1000]`).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gradient [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py#L277) of the `tf.gather` operation returns `IndexedSlices` typed value. In your program, the input the second `tf.gather` is the result of a `tf.matmul` (`mm`). Consequently, the gradient function for matrix multiply is passed an `IndexedSlices` value.

Now, imagine what the gradient function for `tf.matmul` needs to do. To compute the gradient w.r.t `W`, it has to multiply the incoming gradients with the transpose of `Xi`. In this case, the incoming gradients is a `IndexedSlices` type, and `Xi`'s transpose is a dense tensor (`Tensor`) type. TensorFlow doesn't have an implementation of matrix multiply that can operate on `IndexedSlices` and `Tensor`. So it simply converts the `IndexedSlices` to a `Tensor` before calling `tf.matmul`.

If you look at the code for that conversion function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py#L53), you'll notice that it prints out a warning when this sparse to dense conversion might result in either a very large dense tensor (`_LARGE_SPARSE_NUM_ELEMENTS` determines how large), or a dense tensor of unknown size. When you shape your placeholder `X` with shape `[10, None]`, this conversion happens on a `IndexedSlices` with unknown shape (really, only one of the dimension is unknown, but still it's not possible to determine the resulting shape statically), hence you see the warning printed out. Once you set the shape of `X` to `[10, 1000]`, the shape of `IndexedSlices` becomes fully specified, *AND* the resulting dense tensor size is within the threshold, so you don't see the warning printed out.

For your computation, if you simply cannot avoid the `tf.gather` on the result of a `tf.matmul`, then I would worry about this warning too much, unless the number of columns in `X` is extremely large.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I was actually able to restructure my code to use `tf.dynamic_partition()` instead of `tf.gather()`, which made for cleaner implementation in addition to avoiding the warning.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov would you please share your solution with dynamic_partition?